# Anythingslider: Need to remove slides before the active page without easing

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

with Anythingslider and Ajax I made a slider that produce infinity slides. That works great.
But I have to clean the old slides, that the page get not to big and kill the RAM.

I'm trying the following to have the possibility to go always 10 sliders back:

```
  onSlideComplete: function(slider) {


     if (slider.currentPage >= 21) {

    $('#slider1 > li:not(.cloned)').slice(0, 9).remove();
    $('#slider1').anythingSlider(11); // update the slider


 }

      }
```

I dont want the easing effect when I change the slider number to correct the deletion. Is that possible. Or there some better ways?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get a chance to test this, but try the following:

```
onSlideComplete: function(slider) {

    if (slider.currentPage >= 21) {

        $('#slider1 > li:not(.cloned)').slice(0, 9).remove();
        slider.currentPage = 11;
        slider.updateSlider();
    }

}
```

if that doesn't work, try the following:

```
onSlideComplete: function(slider) {

    if (slider.currentPage >= 21) {

        $('#slider1 > li:not(.cloned)').slice(0, 9).remove();
        slider.currentPage = 11;
        slider.updateSlider();

        // (page, autoplay?, callback, time)
        slider.gotoPage(11, false, {}, 0)
    }

}
```

And if that still doesn't work, move the `updateSlider()` after the `gotoPage`. After all that and if it still doesn't work, I think I might need to modify the plugin.